# Loading custom php.ini on Docker (image: php:8.1.2-apache)

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose

I'm trying to load my custom .ini file

I've tried mounting the `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d` directory to `./php` so that I can add .ini files, but it doesn't work, I mean the local directory `php` gets created but it's empty.

One more thing I'm curious about, what if the same config already exists in any of those already loaded `.ini` file, will my custom `.ini` will overwrite those? (That's actually what I want).

This is my `Dockerfile`

```sh
FROM php:8.1.2-apache

RUN apt-get update

# 1. development packages
RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zip \
    curl \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    g++


# 2. apache configs + document root
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf


# 3. mod_rewrite for URL rewrite and mod_headers for .htaccess extra headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin-
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers


# 4. start with base php config, then add extensions
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bz2 \
    intl \
    iconv \
    bcmath \
    opcache \
    calendar \
    pdo_mysql \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip

# 5. composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

And here's the `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:

  # Laravel App
  laravel:
    build:
      context: '.'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      # - ./php:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d  (This doesn't work)

  # MySQL
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./run/var:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

  # Meilisearch
  meilisearch:
    image: getmeili/meilisearch:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./meilisearch/data.ms:/data.ms
    environment:
    - MEILI_MASTER_KEY=${MEILISEARCH_KEY}

networks:
  default:
    name: nginxproxymanager_default
    external: true
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

Set path direct to file

```
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./Docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
```

Check my docker-compose for more information: https://github.com/JavierAgueroCL/docker-php7.4-with-db-extensions/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Got this error: 
`Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/e/Websites/laravel/MyWebsite/docker/php/local.ini" to rootfs at "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini" caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`

Comment: Maybe someone will help Docker php doc reference https://hub.docker.com/_/php#:~:text=The%20default%20config%20can%20be%20customized%20by%20copying%20configuration%20files%20into%20the%20%24PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/%20directory.